# [Edit my log code ]No textureview photo saved despite pressing camera button

Tags: android, threadpool, textureview

I am making a custom camera using camera API2 and textureview.
When saving pictures using textureview, the following issues occur: Sometimes I can't save the picture and the following error code occurs.I have newly attached the log code according to the comments below. I can solve this problem should help.

```
protected void takePicture() {
    if (null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "mCameraDevice is null, return");
        return;
    }

    try {
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) 
      getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = 
        characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        if (map != null) {
            jpegSizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            Log.d("TEST", "map != null " + jpegSizes.length);
        }
        int width = 1280;
        int height =960;
        if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
          for (int i = 0 ; i < jpegSizes.length; i++) {
               Log.d("TEST", "getHeight = " + jpegSizes[i].getHeight() + ", getWidth = " + 
        jpegSizes[i].getWidth());
           }
            //width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            width = 1440;
            //height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            height = 1080;
        }

        ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
        outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = 
        cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, 
       CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);



        // Orientation
        int rotation = ((Activity) 
         getActivity()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        int sensorOrientation =  characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

        int surfaceRotation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);

        int jpegOrientation = (surfaceRotation + sensorOrientation + 270) % 360;

        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, jpegOrientation);

        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");

        //final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM", "pic_" + 
       dateFormat.format(date) + ".jpg");
        File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Pictures" , "/FitMe");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String fileName = dateFormat.format(date)+".jpg";
        ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new 
          ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
             @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image image = null;
                try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                    buffer.get(bytes);

                    if(Camera_change_number==1){

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, 
  options);

                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();


                        matrix.setScale(-1,1);




                        matrix.postRotate(90);


                        bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 1440, 1080, matrix, true);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] front_picture = stream.toByteArray();

                       bytes = front_picture;

                    }



                    save(bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "[junsu] save()");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (image != null) {
                        image.close();
                        reader.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                OutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                    output.write(bytes);
                    output.flush();
                } finally {
                    if (null != output) {
                        output.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPicture");
        thread.start();
        final Handler backgroudHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, backgroudHandler);

        //final Handler delayPreview = new Handler();

        final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new 
           CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //delayPreview.postDelayed(mDelayPreviewRunnable, 1000);
              //startPreview();
                createCameraPreviewSession();
            }

        };

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, backgroudHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {


                Log.d(TAG, "onConfigureFailed: ");
            }
        }, backgroudHandler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gnLP.png)

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't post the error code a little better. But I desperately need help.!!!

Comment: What android version are you testing on? Also, are you sure your device is API2 compatible? Which device model is it?

Comment: I am testing android 9, API 28 in version and I am using Galaxy S8+ (Android9, API28). I don't think there's a problem with my model because I know it applies from 21. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Anyway the errors doesn't seem to be a crash What is the output? is it a black image? Are you receiving any data at all? Have you tried debugging it and where's the braking point then? Also I can't remember if errors are logged when using printStackTrace(). Please change them to Log.e(TAG, "Error", e)

Comment: Don't be able to store some sometimes when he took the picture. For example, if you take 5 pictures, only 4 pictures are taken. It doesn't look black and it doesn't show any signs of being stored at all. Log in printStackTrace().I'll change it to e. Thank you.

Comment: I have attached a new log code. I'd like to ask if I can find my problem here, too.

Comment: I have tested your code an it works perfectly to me so it could be a parallelism problem, for example two pictures being saved at the same time. I have tested it and it seems to be (correctly) overriden. Maybe is not your desired behaviour. As you are not sure if it is being saved or not you should add more logs to see what parts of your methods executes. Even to see your variable values.